# FTP permissions problem

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp

I have vsftpd installed on ubuntu. I added a new created a new user and set the users home path to `/var/www` so I can ftp with that user directly to that location. And that all works, I can now FTP with the user I created directly to that location. However I whenever I ftp, I have no permissions to change anything. How can I change that?

Thanks!!

## UPDATE

OK, I set my user as the owner and confirmed the ownership. I even chmod the directory and its contents to 777 and verified that. I can make any change I want locally however I cannot make any changes via ftp. when using filezilla i get `Critical file transfer error` I also get an error when trying to modify a file with dreamweaver via ftp.

I am new to linux so I don't have any idea what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used vsftpd on Ubuntu in the past, and by default it is locked down to prevent any kind of write access regardless of the permissions.  To fix this you need to make sure the following line in `/etc/vsftpd.conf` is uncommented and then restart vsftpd:

First, from a terminal window, edit the config file for vsftpd:

> sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf

Or you can use gedit to alter the file if you prefer:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Then find the following section:

```
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
#write_enable=YES
```

and change it to this (remove the # in front of the second line) and make sure it is set to YES:

```
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
```

And then restart your vsftpd process (or just reboot your computer):

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

And then you should have write access as long as your user has the correct permissions.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was really getting frustrated with this one! :)

Comment: It had me banging my head off the desk for a while too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you need to switch ownership for /var/www to that user

Easy way is

chown -R user: /var/www

The -R handles everything below also

Comment: am I supposed to replace `user` with the username I want to change? Thanks

Comment: yes.. change user to the user you want to give rights to